# Site no longer working following server crash - how to restore it

Tags: 500-internal-error, internal-server-error

I have a site that suddenly stopped working earlier due to what I can only assume was the server going down. Now I can connect using ftp but in the browser I get the following. Any advice on how to get the site back again gratefully received.

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@websitename and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: What does your host say?

Comment: Not been able to get through to them. Awaited ticket to be answered.

Comment: Might be time to find a new host man, that's pretty pathetic customer service for a site that's down.

Comment: Maybe but that is not the solution to my immediate problem

Comment: Well, 500 is the generic error code when the server doesn't have any more information to give you, so it's hard to help you troubleshoot.  Do you have access to error logs?  Can you get to the admin section?

Comment: Do you mean the dashboard? I can't access anything via a browser and can only see files via cpanel and ftp. The error log is downloading but is enormous. I am sure I have had this before and I simply copied the wp-admin up folder again. Any idea if this works?

Comment: If you haven't modified core, yes, you can reupload the same version of wp-admin with no ill effects.  Might as well upload a fresh copy of wp-includes while you're at it too.

Comment: great - my last question is how would can I tell which version I was on. I put off updating 3.8 .... was going to do that later :_

Comment: Take a look at version.php in wp-includes, good luck.

Comment: Sure thing, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do have ftp access, edit your wp-config.php add these lines:

```
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
define('WP_DEBUG', true);  // Turn debugging ON
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false); // Turn forced display OFF
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);  // Turn logging to wp-content/debug.log
```

at the same time, comment out any lines that define `WP_DEBUG` as false. Then do a page reload and finally look at what is logged in `wp-content/debug.log` 
that should at least give you an idea as to what is causing the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simply to use ftp to rename the old wp-admin and wp-includes folders and upload a new copy. Worked straight away. Thanks